# Saving images and videos for offline access

Tags: flutter, dart, offline, flutter-dependencies

I am developing an app that fetches a custom object from my REST API. The object's class is called `MyItem` and it looks like this:

```
class MyItem {
  String title;
  String profilePicURL;
  String videoURL;
}
```

As you can see, the class contains two URLs, that points to a `png` and `mp4` files.

I would like to implement a feature, which allows the user to download the object, in order to access its content offline. I have no problem saving the `title` property, but how can I save the two URLs (because I don't want the URL itself to be saved, I would like to save the file it points to).

Any idea what is the best way doing that in Flutter and Dart?

Thank you!

Comment: you can use dio [here](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

Comment: @KrishBhanushali Can you please explain a bit more? I have read the docs, but offline access is not mentioned there

Comment: What you can do is save or download a video to a particular location , here you can use path provider package, now just fetch that location or path to your video player. Ping if you didnt understand I will put up some snippets too

Comment: @KrishBhanushali I am new to Flutter so I didn't 100% understand yet. If you can post a snippet it will be very helpful :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Dio dio = Dio();
    



   //Below function will download the file you want from url and save it locally
    void Download(String title, String downloadurl) async{
    
try{
await dio.download(downloadurl,"${directory.path}/$title.extensionoffile",
              onReceiveProgress: (rec,total){
                print("Rec: $rec, Total:$total");
                setState(() {
                  //just to save completion in percentage
                String  progressString = ((rec/total)*100).toStringAsFixed(0)+"%";
    
                }
                );
              });
}
catch(e){

//Catch your error here
}
}
```

Now again wherever you want just use

```
var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String filepath = "{directory.path}/filename.fileextension";
```

Now you can use this `Image.file('filepath');` //to display those image
also you can use
[video player plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)
where again `VideoPlayerController.file('filepath')` //to show video but read documention properly

These are just a whole steps or a broader view, you need to use them as a map and build your code.That is have a proper file name and extension saved or correctly fetched or mapped